# How to pass the current windows credential to a WCF REST service from a Windows 8 Native app made using JS?

Tags: windows, rest, windows-8, wcf-rest, windows-runtime

I am trying to call a WCF REST service from my windows 8 app and I'm always prompted for the credential. I have Default Windows Credentials activated in the package manifest and am looking for the equivalent of

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler(); 
handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

when using javascript.

The service is set up to use windows auth and works fine when called from IE9.

Comment: Have you found the solution ? I have the same problem ..

Comment: Hi KANAX, I never really found a solution for this at the time. If I remember correctly, I had to stop using WinJS for this and move to C# where there was never a problem. Sorry I can't be of any more help, I don't remember the details.

Comment: Okay thank you for your response! I'm still searching a solution to this for my part

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Winjs.xhr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229787.aspx) for the call. Make sure [defaultWindowsCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211380) are set in appxmanifest (as you said they are).

Sample usage:

```
WinJS.xhr({
    url: requestUrl, user: 'username', pass: 'password, headers: { accept: 'application/json'}
}).then(
    function (req) {
    var data = JSON.parse(req.response);
    document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = data.d[0].;
    // Now call the user-supplied callback function when this data is ready
    c({
       results: data.d,
        number: data.d.length
    });
},  //Error func
    function (req) {
    e(req);
}, //progress func
    function (req) {
    p(req);
}
);
```

You could also user a c# project to take care of WCF communication and have the Javascript project cal it's methods.

Other authetication paths:

The [Windows.Security.Authentication.Live](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.authentication.live.aspx) "Enables Metro style apps to use Windows Live to authenticate users using their Windows Live ID"

Also take a look at [Metro style app for banking: code walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464943.aspx) with several authentication scenarios and to [Web Authentication](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122).

[Live SDK Developer Preview](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=28195) will lso enable you to "Take advantage of single sign-on scenarios using Windows Live ID in Windows Developer Preview".

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot!

Is there anyway I can get the application to use the current security context instead of prompting the user for credentials ? The C# code works for this but I was looking for a WinJS equivalent.